# RuntimeError: Error reading network: cannot parse future versions: 10

Tags: python, pycharm, openvino

I am trying to run the multi_camera_multi_person_tracking_demo.py from the PyCharm using the openvino library which I installed as follows:

```
conda install openvino-ie4py -c openvino
```

Then I try to run the multi_camera_multi_person_tracking_demo.py script using the following command:

```
python multi_camera_multi_person_tracking.py -i face-demographics-walking.mp4 --m_detector person-detection-retail-0013.xml --m_reid person-reidentification-retail-0103.xml --config config.py
```

After running this command, I get the following error:

```
    INFO: 2020-05-23 19:08:19: Reading configuration file config.py
INFO: 2020-05-23 19:08:19: Opening file face-demographics-walking.mp4
INFO: 2020-05-23 19:08:19: Creating Inference Engine
INFO: 2020-05-23 19:08:19: Initializing Inference Engine plugin for CPU
INFO: 2020-05-23 19:08:19: Loading network files:
        person-detection-retail-0013.xml
        person-detection-retail-0013.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_camera_multi_person_tracking.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "multi_camera_multi_person_tracking.py", line 248, in main
    capture.get_num_sources())
  File "C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\MultiPerson\utils\network_wrappers.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.net = load_ie_model(ie, model_path, device, None, ext_path, num_reqs=max_num_frames)
  File "C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\MultiPerson\utils\ie_tools.py", line 72, in load_ie_model
    net = IENetwork(model=model_xml, weights=model_bin)
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 415, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IENetwork.__cinit__
RuntimeError: Error reading network: cannot parse future versions: 10
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Following are the details of my system:

```
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit 
Python version: `Python 3.7.7 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`
PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4
cv2 version: 4.2.0
openvino toolkit 2020.2.117.
CPU Device
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an incompatibility issue caused by using an older version with the latest IR v10. Upgrading to the latest OpenVINO version will fix issue.